# Type deduction in C++ for positional information

Tags: c++, types

Let's assume I have a collection of functions following the following pattern:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
T example(Args ... args, T* defaultValue);
```

Furthermore I have another function that operates on these collections:

```
template <auto Function, typename T, typename ... Args>
auto transform(Args ... args) {
    // ...
    T defaultValue /* = ... */;
    auto result = Function(args... , &defaultValue);
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

For example the `transform` function can be used like

```
auto result = transform<ExampleFunction, ExampleT>(int a, int b, int c);
```

The compiler completes the types for `Args`. But I have the problem that I have to specify `T`. However I know that `T` is always the last type of the parameters of `Function`.

Is there a way to "teach" the compiler this property so I can call the `transform`
function without specifying `T`?

```
auto result = transform<ExampleFunction>(int a, int b, int c);
```

### Example

In vulkan there are these functions `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties` and such. You always have to call these functions twice to retrieve some data. I want to create a function `listify` which returns this data as vector.

```
template <auto Function, typename T, typename ... Args>
auto listify(Args ... args)
{
    uint32_t size;
    Function(args... , &size, nullptr);
    std::vector<T> result(size);
    Function(args... , &size, result.data());
    return result;
}
```

I would like to call this function like so

```
auto result = listify<vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties>(nullptr);
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Going deep down the varargs hole is not always the best plan.

Comment: so you want to get parameters of function, especially the last. I believe you can find many resource on that.

Comment: You can't have a variable after a parameter pack.

Comment: `decltype(Function(args..., nullptr))`? Assuming it actually returns `T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the parameters from function.

for example you can do something like this

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template<typename F>
struct last_arg{};

template<typename ret, typename ...args>
struct last_arg<ret(*)(args...)>{
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<sizeof...(args)-1,std::tuple<args...>>;
};

template <auto F, typename ...Args>
auto f(Args... args) {
    // in this case it's unlikely you'd want to specify T, so you can move it out from template parameter
    using T=std::remove_pointer_t<typename last_arg<decltype(F)>::type>;
    
    T defaultValue;
    auto result = F(args... , &defaultValue);
    return result;
}

int bar(int,int*);
void foo(){
    f<bar>(1);
}
```

(this assumes the function is not a function object, but that's also possible)

Comment: That surprisingly works, thanks :D

Comment: I'd replace the `typename T = ...` with a local `using T = ...;`. It doesn't matter much in this case, because it's impossible to pass a custom argument to `T`, but in general it protects against the extra template arguments.